# div Displaying in <div style=",,,"> format but not when put into separate css file

Tags: css, html

I am new to these forums and coding in general.  I am having trouble understanding why

```
<div style="opacity:0.5;position:absolute;left: 650px;width:300px;height:150px;background-color:#40B3DF"></div>
```

works fine, displaying a semi-transparent blue square. While when I enter the following does not.

HTML

```
<div id="textbox"></div>
```

CSS

```
#textbox {

left: 500px;
width:300px;
height:150px;
background-color:#40B3DF;
opacity:0.5;
position:absolute;
}
```

The rest of my css file seems to be working fine with my HTML. Just this one.

I could post the rest of the file if anyone thinks it would help. I am using a CSS Reset code I found online to make it more easily compatible with multiple browsers.

Comment: Are you linking your HTML to your stylesheet?

Comment: More than one element with the same id?

Comment: Where are you adding the CSS? In an external file or inside the HTML page?

Comment: Your browser could be caching your external style sheet, and not the inline styles. Happened to me before. Press CTRL + f5. P.S. Get firebug

Comment: try to use css using class instead of Id. It may possible that you have multiple element with same Id

Comment: Hello everyone. thank you for the fast replies and willingness to help a noobie out.  Yes i have a link to HTML.  I've tried what everyone else has said to no avail.  Here is my code, with the problems toward the bottom:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pkdkh/3/

I could just not enter it in the css file and just do it in the .html file.  But this is just puzzling me :?

Comment: !Doctype after tags are not allowed! DIV with given space need that space to be visible. hacks are nice, but just in case you want a not valid markup. wrong sorted tags and css closing brakets, corrected fiddle at http://jsbin.com/ukoziw/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working for me without any issue. see the following sample link,

http://jsfiddle.net/Pkdkh/

Note: If you are having that style inside separate css file, you have to add the reference to that file in your html

```
<div style="opacity:0.5;position:absolute;left: 650px;width:300px;height:150px;background-color:#40B3DF"></div>
<div id="textbox"></div>

#textbox {
    left: 100px;
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#40B3DF;
    opacity:0.5;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**Update**

---

see the working sample with your updated code,

http://jsfiddle.net/Pkdkh/2/

The problem is you are missing some closing brackets in `#container2` and `#textbox` styles

Comment: This should be a comment. "Works for me" doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: hmmm.  thanks for the speedy reply.  yes it is working there in what you posted, but would you have any idea why it isnt working here?

http://jsfiddle.net/Pkdkh/1/

Perhaps the box is somewhere hidden underneath one of the elements?

Comment: @Juhana: Can you see the working sample? for the current question, answer is there. if he change the question i will update the answer as well. and yes it is working for me. and not working for you? if this is not an answer he will comment it right? and if this is not an answer for his question, that is not a question either.

Comment: @DavidJhoo: did you see the note in my answer? If you are having that style inside separate css file, you have to add the reference to that file in your html

Comment: Sorry I didn't update the code. Here is the updated code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pkdkh/1/

the problem is at the bottom of both the css file and html file where id="textbox" and #textbox

Comment: Ah!  Thank you very much Chamika.  I've been trying to figure it out for hours, and all it was was some missing brackets. :|  Thank you.

Comment: I have undeleted this answer, Chamika. Note that it was deleted in its *original* state, when it was not actually an answer at all, but pretty much just a link. Your improvement in your edit made it a valid answer, so I have reinstated it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for unrelenting. and it was deleted after accepting. you can see the revision of the answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16573162/revisions

Comment: Whether or not it was accepted has nothing to do with it, really. We're here to be a repository of *questions and answers*... not links to external sites. I did not "relent"; you did, by editing to make it an acceptable answer, which was very appreciated :)

Comment: Agreed with you. What i want to tell you is, he just deleted my answer after i edited. and it is accepted just after edited. You can see the revisions. revision 1 is initial edit. revision2 is the actual edit you are talking about. then it is accepted. then someone deleted. and then because of the deletion i just do some changes. but those are not updates to the answer. it is just removing old answer and rollback.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps it is the missing align: which should precede left, in line 4

Left is a property of the align attribute.  It happens that Firefox does pass code when some small thing is missing, even seeming to display correctly, but Chrome will stop display at some point around the error.

Perhaps this is why mixed results?  This is happening to me quite a bit as I try converting from old html to html5, probably why I noticed it.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2